# VB.Net If statement to check if a specific image from my resources is loaded

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to use an `If` statment to check if a specific image from my resources is loaded.

I want to change the image when it is clicked as in:

```
If PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.BIKE13 Then
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.BIKE13_Helmet
End If
```

I'm going to use several `ElseIf` Statements

---

After some search I found several ways to do it but I have about 20-30 images and I'm and I need a simple method.

(VS 2010)

Comment: You can store something in the .Tag property to indicate which image is assigned.  Or use an imagelist and store the key

Comment: Can you give me an example how to do this if possible? im newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code cannot possibly work for two reasons. Firstly, an `Image` is a reference type object, so to compare like that you would have to use the `Is` operator rather than `=`. Secondly, `My.Resources` creates a new object each time, so even using `Is` will never give you a match.

What you need to do is use the `My.Resources` property once and once only and assign the `Image` object to a member variable.  You can then use `Is` with that field.

E.g.

```
Private bike13Image As Image = My.Resources.BIKE13
Private bike13HelmetImage As Image = My.Resources.BIKE13_Helmet
```

and

```
If PictureBox1.Image Is bike13Image Then
    PictureBox1.Image = bike13HelmetImage
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer mate i got your point the code you gave me works except the if using only 'PictureBox1.Image = bike13HelmetImage' the image show up but with the if statment it wont

Comment: I'm not sure that you have thought that through.  What is the point of the `If` statement?  It is to display `bike13HelmetImage` if and only if `bike13Image` is already displayed.  If that's not what you want then what have you got an `If` statement for in the first place?

Comment: bike13Image is allready displayed by a combobox which you select a bike then you must click a button to display the helmet of that bike for example.

Comment: I just based my code on yours, which appeared to be testing whether the `PictureBox` was already displaying a specific `Image`.  If that's not what you want then don;t write code to do that.  It's your code.  You write it the way you want.