# How to compare two image uisng vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, image, compare

I got the image in the resources in my project.

I assign the image to the button by using
`btnViewProductRemove.Image = My.Resources.btnRemove`

Then I wish to compare the image because if the image is My.Resources.btnRemove then I wish to perform remove action, else I wish to perform recover action.
Here is my coding:

```
If btnViewProductRemove.Image.Equals(My.Resources.btnRemove) Then
        'Perform Remove
    Else
        'Perform Recover
End If
```

However, this code does not working. Maybe the bitmap is different? But there are same image. How do I can compare two image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.Net If statement to check if a specific image from my resources is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811840/vb-net-if-statement-to-check-if-a-specific-image-from-my-resources-is-loaded)

Comment: This, while possible, would be extremely inefficient and wasteful. Set an additional int or bool value somewhere you can check instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`My.Resources.btnRemove` is a property that returns a new instance of an image every time. You *could* make it work by holding onto a reference of your resource images, but it’s kind of inappropriate to decide what to do based on a button’s image. The `Tag` property would be marginally more appropriate: set `btnViewProductRemove.Tag = "remove"` or `= "recover"` at the same time as you set its image, then just compare that.

```
If CStr(btnViewProductRemove.Tag) = "Remove" Then
    ' Remove
Else
    ' Recover
End If
```

If you can, though, I’d try to make the Remove and Recover buttons two separate controls, with only one of them visible at a time.