# How to check if a specific image is in ann picturebox | VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make an if statement to check if a specific image has been loaded into a picture box, here is my code below:-

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim imgResourceNames = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}
    Dim randImage As New Random
    Dim index = randImage.Next(imgResourceNames.Length)
    Dim imgResourceName = imgResourceNames(Index)
    Dim img = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imgResourceName), Image)


    Private Sub btnOne_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOne.Click
        picOne.Image = img
        picOne.Visible = True

        If picOne.Image Is My.Resources._5 Then
            lblDisplay.Text = "Duck"
        ElseIf picOne.Image Is My.Resources._2 Then
            lblDisplay.Text = "Bee"
        ElseIf picOne.Image Is My.Resources._3 Then
            lblDisplay.Text = "Bird"
        ElseIf picOne.Image Is My.Resources._4 Then
            lblDisplay.Text = "Frog"
        ElseIf picOne.Image Is My.Resources._1 Then
            lblDisplay.Text = "Owl"
        End If

    End Sub
```

However, this piece of code doesn't seem to do what I intended, and there seems to be no errors. I tried using this example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811840/vb-net-if-statement-to-check-if-a-specific-image-from-my-resources-is-loaded), but that doesn't seem to be working either. I've also tried using `If img Is My.Resources._1 ...` but that also seems to not work correctly.

If anyone could help me and tell me how I could fix it, I would be really appreciative, thanks.

Comment: When asking `My.Resources` to fetch an Image, it returns a new Object each time. Since you're comparing references, it will never be the same. You can use a `List(Of Image)` to store your images, fill it beforehand, then use the List methods to locate one (by reference). -- Or build a class object if you need to store more details, as the name of the Image, the Control that currently shows it, if any etc. -- Dispose of the Images you have created when the container Form closes.

Comment: hi @Jimi, how would I do that? Do I create a ```List()``` and store them? I've hardcoded the files in.

Comment: You have *embedded* image files into your executable. Now these images are byte arrays. You could assign meaningful names to those resources, so `imgResourceNames` will contain `{"Owl", "Frog", "Bird", "Bee", "Duck"}`. Then use a Random object to pick a name from this array, store that random value, get the resource Image using that name and also use it to set the Text of the Label.

Comment: ann? Do you mean 'a'?

Comment: No, he means give your resources meaningful names in the first place. If you have an image of a duck then name the resource `Duck`. You would then have "Duck" in your array and you can just put that straight into the `Label`. Naming something "1" is just plain bad. Walk away from that code and come back in a month and you'll have no idea what you were thinking. If you use names that actually mean something, the code will tell you what you were thinking.

Comment: hi @Jimi , I've tried changing the names of the image files in resources, how would I then store the random value in my code?

Comment: @user18387401 I have done that now.